# Program freezes while doing simple for loop

Tags: java

this code:

```
class X {

    private char encryptChar(String input, int pos) {
        //do not worry about "lengtness" it's just for debugging purposes
        int length = keyString.length();//key string is "CD10"
        int pos_ = pos % keyString.length();
        char l_ = input.charAt(pos_);
        char r_ = keyString.charAt(pos_);
        int result = l_ ^ r_;
        char rr = (char) result;
        return (char) result;
    }

    public String encryptString(String message) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length();++i) {
            result.append(encryptChar(message,i));//after one iteration this freezes! why?
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

See the comment two lines above.
O, and I'm using NetBeans 7.0.1

Comment: Where in encryptChar does it freeze?

Comment: Also what is does message look like?

Comment: Run it in debug mode and halt the process when it "freezes".

Comment: @Ryan after first iteration within for loop it freezes. As for message: any longer than 1 char

Comment: What exactly do you mean by freeze? How do you know it freezes?

Comment: I ran it in Eclipse without problems ...

Comment: Right...does it freeze inside the encryptChar() method? Or does it just freeze on the .append() method?  Try putting a breakpoint in encryptChar().

Comment: @Robin I'm not sure I know how to do it.

Comment: You should redesign `encryptChar` and only submit the required `char` to it: `encryptChar(char c)`

Comment: @Ryan I do have breakpoint in encryptChar but it "looks like" it freezes on append

Comment: So encryptChar returns properly? That is, if you put a breakpoint on return and step over it, it returns and THEN freezes?

Comment: @Ryan it works now. Nothing has been changed. It just started working. Unbelivable. Thanks for the time all of you've taken in order to help me.

Comment: no problem - I fixed it with my mind. ;)

Comment: @Ryan Bennett: How did you fix it with your mind? It is running on my machine and I am using Netbeans 7. I need some of that mind so I can fix things without making any changes.

Comment: The code as written doesn't look right. The assignment of input.charAt(pos_) to l_ looks like it will only ever access the first n characters, where n is the length of keyString (and will fail if the input string is shorter than the keyString). I think that should read "char l_ = input.charAt(pos)".

Comment: No it works even if the input is empty ("").

Comment: @Bhesh - Yes, it'll work if the string is empty, because you will never call encryptChar in that case. It will fail if the message length is length 1 to n-1 (where n is the length of the keyString).

Comment: It freezes when I place breakpoint in line: int length = keyString.length();//key string is "CD10"; after removing this breakpoint it works. That's all

Comment: @Rick Goldstein: Did you run the code?

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. Since pos_ is always <= pos, you'll never be trying to access a character past the end of the input string. However, the point stands that you should not be getting input.charAt(pos_), but instead getting input.charAt(pos). (see my comment above and @DwB's answer)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using more meaningful variable names.  There is a bug at this line in the code you posted: `char l_ = input.charAt(pos_);`   instead of "pos_" the parameter should be "pos".

```
    private char encryptChar(String input, int inputPosition)
    {
        char encryptCharacter;
        int encryptPosition = inputPosition % KEY_STRING.length();
        char inputCharacter;
        char returnValue;

        encryptCharacter = KEY_STRING.charAt(encryptPosition);
        inputCharacter = input.charAt(inputPosition);
        returnValue = (char) (encryptCharacter ^ inputCharacter);

        return returnValue;
    }

    private String encryptString(String message)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (int index = 0; index < message.length(); ++index)
        {
            result.append(encryptChar(message, index));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```